# Uploading files of different sizes on sharepoint office365 REST Python Client

Tags: python, rest, office365api, sharepoint-rest-api, office365-rest-client

I want to upload some files to sharepoint via office365 REST Python client.

On documentation on github, I found two examples:

- one for larger files where this is executed:

`uploaded_file = target_folder.files.create_upload_session(local_path, size_chunk, print_upload_progress).execute_query()`

- one for small files :
  `target_file = target_folder.upload_file(name, file_content).execute_query()` .

In my case, I want to be able to upload files who are small and also files who are very large.
For testing, I wanted to see if the method for larger files works with smaller files too.
With a small file, while putting the **size_chunk** at 1Mb, the uploading was done, but the file uploaded was empty (0b), so I lost my content while uploading.

I wanted to know if there is someone who knows how can we do something more generic for whatever size of files. Also I don't understand what is the size chunk for larger files case. Do you know how one should choose it?
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is solved by installing office365-rest-python-client instead of office365-rest-client.